# Electron app with worker thread error on exit

Tags: node.js, multithreading, electron

I'm learning to use worker_threads in electron.js.
My application has the following relevant code:

```
//main.js
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads');
let worker;

//electron stuff here

app.on('ready', function() {
    //more electron stuff
     worker = new Worker('./script.js');
});

//functions to interact with the worker thread
```

And my worker script:

```
//script.js
const { parentPort } = require('worker_threads');
parentPort.on("message", message => {
    console.log(message);
});
```

Everything is fine if I just run the bare bones part in node, but when I run it in electron, I get the following error in console when exiting the application:

```
12 info lifecycle MyProject@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: MyProject@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3221225477
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid MyProject@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd [path]
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.18.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.6
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3221225477
22 error MyProject@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
22 error Exit status 3221225477
23 error Failed at the MyProject@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3221225477, true ]
```

3221225477 seems to be an access violation error from what I've read. The error goes away if I don't create the worker thread, but it persists even if the worker script is completely blank. So this makes me think that I'm not doing cleanup/garbage collection properly. I've tried things like worker.terminate() and removeAllListeners() in main.js when exiting, and process.exit(0) in script.js.

What's the proper way to stop a threaded application in electron?

Edit: For anyone wandering by with a similar problem, I ended up abandoning worker_threads and going with [child_process and forks](https://www.matthewslipper.com/2019/09/22/everything-you-wanted-electron-child-process.html) instead. I think this works cleaner and I haven't encountered any errors yet.